# What are the default values for preCondition and verb when configuring IIS 7.0+ handlers?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, httpmodule

[The documentation on Adding Handlers <add>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/add) specifies the following default values:

```
allowPathInfo       = false
modules             = ManagedPipelineHandler
requireAccess       = Script
resourceType        = Unspecified
responseBufferLimit = 4194304
```

`name` and `path` have no default and are required to be set.

`type` is required only for managed handlers.

`resourceType` is only required only for script map handler mappings.

This leaves us with `preCondition` and `verb`. What are their default values?